# Convert Java to C# or VB.net to C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert code from Java to C# or VB.net to C#?

Answer (score 2):

You could decompile the VB.NET code using Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to get it as C#. You might also try someting like this online converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: i think there isn't for java to c#

Answer (score 1):

Try [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for a free C#/VB code converter. I've used it - it isn't bad. There are also many commercial ones with lots of features.

Java and C# are very similar and converting between the two (and to/from VB) is possible. A quick search should reveal many commercial options.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little bit of both C# and Java, converting Java to C# by hand would be the best route to go. That's what I did for a relativley medium sized Java project. Then you can use Sharpdevelop (http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) to convert C# to VB and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

For Java to C# &VB.Net, you can also use Tangible Java to VB & C# Converter.
[http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_VB_and_CSharp_Converter_Details.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could be useful. But it might not work with complex code structures..

https://varycode.com/converter.html